# encrypted QR code and key size

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, qr-code

So we're doing a project about an attendance system ,the idea that we have an encrypted data in a qrcode that will be sent to a server to be extracted and then decrypted using a key stored in a database on the server.what would be the best encryption technique while maintaining a reasonable key size in the DB keeping in mind that our data will only consist of 8 characters

Comment: May I ask you why you want to encrypt the QR code in the first place? If it's just 8 characters that makes it sound like it's going to be used as a simple index into a large database? If so, why encrypt it at all? The only viable encryption mode for your application would be ECB (electronic codebook), because a QR code can't "change itself" after being scanned / processed. And its trivial to copy. If you're worried about improper inputs, then *signing* might make more sense, but if it's just a lookup index, then simply validating the index being present suffices that.

Comment: @datenwolf thank u for answering i'm encrypting that data itself not the qrcode,so we're using these 8 characters as a kind of pin for attending in the DB besides we have an add manually option so obtaining that pin could compromise the whole process

Comment: And what is stopping anyone from taking a photograph of the QR and using the copy mailciously? Something that is easily copied can not be used as a security token.

Comment: he could but it only matters the 8 characters in the qr code which suppose to be encrypted